# Plotly R: save an image as svg or tiff

Tags: r, svg, plotly, tiff, save-as

I would like to save my plot as .svg or .tiff but as much as I have tried to save it checking several questions, I have not succeeded. The plot is a 3D surface and here is the code.

```
EjeX <- Table$Col1
EjeY <- Table$Col2
EjeZ <- as.matrix(Conc)
Fig1 <- plot_ly(
  x = EjeY, 
  y = EjeX, 
  z = EjeZ
  ) %>% add_surface(
  contours = list(
    z = list(
      show=TRUE,
      usecolormap=TRUE,
      highlightcolor="#ff0000",
      project=list(z=TRUE)
    )
  )
)
Fig1
layout(
  Fig1, scene = list(
    xaxis = list(
      title = "x", 
      range = c(5,15)
      ), 
    yaxis = list(
      title = "y", 
      range = c(100,160)
      ), 
    zaxis = list(
      title = "z", 
      range = c(0,14)
      )
    )
  )
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What methods have you attempted to use to save the content of this plot? Your code isn't meaningful, because you didn't include how you're trying to save it (or your data to make it reproducible). If you are using the modebar that floats at the top right of a Plotly plot, you could look at this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72680199/how-to-export-a-plot-as-static-image-from-plotly-with-high-quality/72680447#72680447). They aren't trying to accomplish the same thing (quality versus output extension). However the answer works for your question, as well.